# Angular Form New Field that I want to capture as variable and add to new SharePoint list upon Submission

Tags: angular

I have an app that a contractor built for us and then left using Angular. I have been able to modify and retrofit a lot of the code to get it to do what we want, but I am very new to Angular so I am not certain how to handle this next task.

I have a new field I add to one of the forms in the app.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
                        <input matInput class="form-control" 
                                id="LearnerWWID" 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="WWID" 
                                value=''
                                formControlName="LearnerWWID"/>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
```

This is where the new field is mentioned. I would like to capture this value in this section of the component.ts code:

```
saveRequest(): void {
console.log('TrgAROneComponent -> saveRequest');
if (this.requestFormTrgAROne.dirty && this.requestFormTrgAROne.valid) {
    // Copy the form values over the product object values
    const p = Object.assign({}, this.requestFormTrgAROne.value);
    this.selTraining = this._requestService._trgUgInv.filter(trg =>
      trg.TrainingCode.toLowerCase() === p.Training.toLowerCase ||
      trg.UserGroupName.toLowerCase() === p.UserGroupName.toLowerCase())[0];
      console.log('TrgAROneComponent -> saveRequest-> this.selTraining', this.selTraining);
    p['TrainingName'] = this.selTraining.TrainingName;
    p['UserGroupName'] = this.selTraining.UserGroupName;
    p['AddWWIDApprovalReq'] = this.selTraining.AddWWIDApprovalReq;
    p['RemoveWWIDApprovalReq'] = this.selTraining.RemoveWWIDApprovalReq;
    p['AudienenceIDGrpOwners'] = this.selTraining.AudienenceIDGrpOwners;
    p['ReqSupportMailbox'] = this._requestService._selReq.ReqSupportMailbox;
    p['ProcessingMailbox'] = this.selTraining.ProcessingMailbox;
    p['RequesterName'] = this._requestService._userProfile.DisplayName;
    p['RequesterEmail'] = this._requestService._userProfile.Email;
    p['RequesterWWID'] = this._requestService._userProfile.WWID;
    p['ReqContentTypeId'] = this._requestService._selReq.ReqContentTypeId;
    p['SharedApprovalMailbox'] = this.selTraining.SharedApprovalMailbox;
    p['LearnerWWID'] = what goes here?  
    // Decide if approval is required
    p['IsApprovalReq'] = this.isApprovalRequired(p);
    console.log('TrgAROneComponent -> saveRequest-> p', p);
    this._trgaroneService.saveRequest(p).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log('TrgAROneComponent ->saveRequest- > result', result);
        // this.requestFormTrgAROne.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['/reqmgmt/confirm']);
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
        console.log('TrgAROneComponent ->saveRequest- > error', error);
      }
    );
}
```

}

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Regards,

Adam

Comment: you are basically copying your form `requestFormTrgAROne` value in object `p`. if your form has key-value for `LearerWWID`, then `p` will also have the same.

Comment: just so I am clear where is that key-value set? This is a new field that wasn't previously included on the form.

Comment: I suppose you have a reactive form, have you made a `FormControl` for `LearerWWID` ?

Comment: yes its defined in this div on the form.

        <div class="form-group">
                        <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
                            <textarea matInput class="form-control" 
                                    id="requestDescriptionId" 
                                    placeholder="Business Justification (Required)"
                                    rows=3
                                    formControlName="RequestDescription"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>